# Alternatives to Pieceable

Tags: ios, browser

Currently we are using pieceable to allow users to demo our iOS app (enterprise) in browser before they invest in purchasing a fleet of devices for their employees. The problem is that pieceable was acquired by facebook back in 2012 and it pretty much looks like they've dropped off the face of the earth. Confusing because it's such and awesome product.

Just wondering if anyone knows any solid alternatives to pieceable to upload your app to and have it run in a browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am one of the developers working on [Appetize.io](https://appetize.io). It's very much like Pieceable in that it streams apps to web browsers, but uses pure HTML5 + Javascript, and supports both iOS and Android.

Comment: Hi weiyin, Awesome stuff. The problem that i have is that it doesnt seem to work in internet explorer? Any ideas there?

Comment: @Raven Internet Explorer 9.0 and before do not work, IE 10 has some issues we are working on, and IE 11 should work well. We are adding support for more web browsers, so check back later.

Comment: Awesome stuff. Such a great product Weiyin.